# how to plot a pie chart row wise?

Tags: python, pandas, pie-chart

If the data is like:

> one  two
>   123456 98765
>   456767 45678
>   123454 87654

Then how a pie chart can be formed for say 1st row values ie values  `123456` ,`98765`in pandas ?

I tried codes which are given on internet as:

`df.T.plot.pie(subplots=True, figsize=(9, 3))`

and

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df.Data.plot(kind='pie')

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6,6), dpi=200)
ax = plt.subplot(111)

df.Data.plot(kind='pie', ax=ax, autopct='%1.1f%%', startangle=270, fontsize=17)
```

but these codes don't plot row values instead giving a cloumn result.

Comment: Where do you get stuck? Can you provide some code example? Or take a look at [selecting data](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html) and [plotting a pie chart](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.pie.html).

Comment: I have updated my code, kindly have a look in main section @Elletlar Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get row-wise pie plots, you can iterate the rows and plot each row:

```
In [1]: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
   ...: import pandas as pd
   ...: import seaborn as sns
   ...:
   ...: sns.set(palette='Paired')
   ...: %matplotlib inline

In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['one', 'two'], data=[[123456, 98765],[456767, 45678],[123454, 87654]])

In [3]: df.head()
Out[3]:
      one    two
0  123456  98765
1  456767  45678
2  123454  87654

In [4]: for ind in df.index:
   ...:     fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
   ...:     fig.set_size_inches(5,5)
   ...:     df.iloc[ind].plot(kind='pie', ax=ax, autopct='%1.1f%%')
   ...:     ax.set_ylabel('')
   ...:     ax.set_xlabel('')
   ...:
<matplotlib.figure.Figure at 0x1e8b4205c50>
<matplotlib.figure.Figure at 0x1e8b41f56d8>
<matplotlib.figure.Figure at 0x1e8b4437438>
```

[image: Row-wise pie plots]

EDIT:

To plot only a specific row, you are selecting with `.iloc` the row you want to plot (e.g., row 0).

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
fig.set_size_inches(5,5)
df.iloc[0].plot(kind='pie', ax=ax, autopct='%1.1f%%')
ax.set_ylabel('')
ax.set_xlabel('')
```

See documentation on [Indexing and Selecting Data](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html)

Comment: Thanks @Benjamin it works for all the row. But how can a pie chart can be plot for a specific row only...say for `row[0]` ??

Comment: Hi Surya, I've extended my answer.

Comment: got it... Thanks @Benjamin